# A std::chrono clocks allows to use a floating-point representation with a fractional component

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

Would it be permissible for an implementation to provide a clock that uses a floating-point representation and has a period greater than the resolution of the clock?

If the period is greater than the resolution, then the floating point value of duration might have a fractional part.  Or in code:

```
const auto t = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
modf(t.time_since_epoch().count(), &dummy) != 0;
```

If the underling representation of the clock is an integral type, then clearly the above comparison must be false.  With a floating point representation it is possible, but is that allowed by the standard?

An example would be a `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` that has a resolution of one microsecond and is defined as:

```cpp
class high_resolution_clock {
  public:
    typedef double rep;
    typedef ratio<1, 1> period; // Note, 1 sec period > 1 µs resolution
    typedef chrono::duration<rep, period> duration;
```

This would be very similar to how Python `time.time()` returns the system time.

`rep` and `period` are unspecified in the standard, but there are some constraints from N4860 §27.3 Table 97 [time.clock.req]:

- `rep` must be "[a]n arithmetic type or a class emulating an arithmetic type"
- `period` must be "a specialization of ratio"
- `period` is "[t]he tick period of the clock in seconds"

The use of double clearly satisfies the requirements of `rep` and the `period` is clearly a ratio.  What remains is: is `period` the tick period of the clock?

It's not clear to me what this means exactly.  Does the tick period represent the greatest precision the clock may use?  E.g., the remainder of time_since_epoch(), converted to seconds with no loss of precision, and then divided by the period must be zero.  Which of course must be true when `rep` is an integral type, but for a floating point type it might not hold.  This interpretation would seems to disallow the clock described above.

Or does it mean the clock should increment in steps of `period`, but it might be possible to report the time of a tick to sub-period precision?  This is common in precision time stamping.  It is common for a GPS timing module to provide a pulse-per-second (PPS) output.  This pulse can not be generated at an infinitely precise instant in time and might be limited to perhaps 10 ns steps.  However, the error between the 10 ns step the PPS is generated on and a more precise instant it should have appeared at can be calculated, and this reported by the hardware as a correction value.  Thus, one has a clock that ticks every second, yet each tick is reported with a non-zero picosecond level of precision.

Or is the `period` only meant to allow conversion of the duration from `time_since_epoch()` into seconds?  Neither the precision of the clock nor the expected time between ticks need have any relation to it.

Comment: It seems that if the standard doesn't explicitly require integral durations, then there are no requirements placed on how this class is incremented, and it is likely to differ between systems.

Comment: It is the requirement that period be "the tick period of the clock" that might require no fractional times.

Comment: It doesn't explicitly say so. Interpolation might be a valid use case. Or maybe you want to represent the average of several durations. I think in practice, duration will usually be an integral number of periods, but I'm not seeing anything putting this requirement on `duration`. The only restriction is on `period`.

Comment: I'd refer you to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration which implies floating point representation type is expected : *"The only data stored in a duration is a tick count of type Rep. If Rep is floating point, then the duration can represent fractions of ticks. Period is included as part of the duration's type, and is only used when converting between different durations."*

Comment: On real systems, `period` can’t reliably be the actual tick period of the clock as that can’t be determined at compile time (well it *can*, but only for the particular machine the compiler runs on). Rather, it’s the scale the clock uses when reporting time; that is usually static (with a notable exception of Windows’ PerformanceCounter which can’t thus be directly exposed as a clock).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, I think you have missed that `rep` is a double, not `period`.  A floating point representation is certainly not expected, as existing implementations invariably use an integral type.

Comment: @TrentP It wasn't immediately clear to me at first if you meant `period` could be a floating point type as well, but after reading the question again it seemed clear. What I mean by a floating point representation type is expected, I mean that, based on that passage from cppreference I linked and quoted, it seems like that use case was anticipated and accounted for. In the sense that "the language comity expected someone would eventually want a clock with a floating point `rep` type".

Comment: @numzero, indeed knowing the tick period at compile time is practically infeasible.  Even at runtime, the operating system might well not tell us the underlying tick period of the clock.  POSIX has `clock_getres()` but not all operating systems have this.  Yet none the less, the standard does require it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, but the question was not if rep could be floating point, but if the clock could advance in steps smaller that the period.  floating point rep is possible, I think there is no question about that.  And clearly the clock precision being greater than the period is NOT possible, if rep is integral.  That's mathematically required.  But a floating point rep combined with a clock resolution greater than the period?  It's certainly *possible*.  But is it standard conforming?  That seems unclear.

Answer (score 3):

The only requirements on the `std::chrono`-supplied clock's `rep` are:

- `rep` must be an arithmetic type or a class emulating an arithmetic type: https://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.req#tab:time.clock-row-2

And because of the [*Cpp17TrivalClock* requirements](https://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock#general-1):

- `rep` meets the numeric type requirements: https://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.req#4.2
- `rep` is swappable: https://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.req#4.3
- For `system_clock`, `rep` must be signed:  http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock#system.members-1

[Floating-point types](http://howardhinnant.github.io/TypeHiearchy.pdf) meet all of these requirements.

In practice, all `std::chrono`-supplied clocks use a signed integral `rep`.

Note however that it is nearly trivial to supply your own clock:

```
#include <chrono>

struct my_clock
{
    using rep                       = double;
    using period                    = std::ratio<1>;
    using duration                  = std::chrono::duration<rep, period>;
    using time_point                = std::chrono::time_point<my_clock>;
    static constexpr bool is_steady = false;

    static time_point now() noexcept
    {
        return time_point{std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()};
    }
};
```

In this example I based `my_clock` off of `system_clock` but converted the measure to double-based seconds.  `my_clock` is a first-class citizen in the chrono infrastructure.  For example you can `std::this_thread_sleep_until(my_clock::now() + 1s)`.

That is, you can add `duration`s to your custom `time_point`, and use it in std-supplied functions expecting a `time_point`.

You could also form your own floating-point `time_point` based on a `std::chrono`-supplied clock.  For example:

```
using dsec = std::chrono::duration<double>;
using dtp = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, dsec>;

dtp tp = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::cout << std::fixed << tp.time_since_epoch().count() << '\n';
```

The above forms a `duration` based on `double` with a period of `seconds`, and a `time_point` based on `system_clock`, and the double-based `seconds`.

This just output for me:

```
1631145273.043276
```

In short, *yes*, floating-point-based clocks can tick in amounts that are fractions of their declared `period`.

Comment: What about the "Operational Semantics" column for "C1::period" in that first table you linked to?  Is this only meant to be informative and not a requirement?  Because "C1::period [is] The tick period of the clock ..." from the standard and your statement that "clocks can tick in amounts that are fractions of their declared period," seem to contradict each other.  Unless we say the tick period of the clock and the amount the clock ticks in are are not the same thing, despite the similarity of the wording.

Comment: I guess you have a point.  I wrote those words (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2661.htm#Clocks).  But it was intended to be descriptive and not limit a floating-point based clock in the way you've described.  I would not object to this wording being changed by an [LWG issue](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#submit_issue) to better describe the intent.  Though I'm not sure of what the improved wording would look like.

Comment: Ah, how about: must be the same type as `C1::duration::period`.  It's a bit circular though.  That might draw greater criticism.